# Growth rate of the nth natural number not constructable with n steps of addition and multiplication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recursion, upper-lower-bounds

While messing around with the idea of ordinal collapsing functions, I stumbled upon an interesting simple function:

$$C(0)=\{0,1\}\\C(n+1)=C(n)\cup\{\gamma+\delta:\gamma,\delta\in C(n)\}\\\psi(n)=\min\{k\notin C(n),k>0\}$$

The explanation is simple. We start with $\{0,1\}$ and repeatedly add it's elements to themselves:

$C(1)=\{0,1,2\}\\
C(2)=\{0,1,2,3,4\}\\
C(3)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}\\\vdots\\C(n)=[0,2^n]$

And $\psi(n)$ is defined as the smallest integer not within $C(n)$, which is $2^n+1$.

---

I then extended my function. Imagine all the same definition, except that we now have

$$C(n+1)=C(n)\cup\{\gamma+\delta,\color{red}{\gamma\cdot\delta}:\gamma,\delta\in C(n)\}$$

This simple change gives us something a bit more complicated. The first few sets are

$C(1)=\{0,1,2\}\\
C(2)=\{0,1,2,3,4\}\\
C(3)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,16\}\\
C(4)=\small\left\{\begin{align}0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30,\\ 32, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 49, 54, 56, 60, 63, 64, 72, 80, 81, 84, 96, 108, 112, 128, 144, 192, 256\end{align}\right\}\\
C(5)=\{0,\dots,177,179,\dots\}\\
\vdots$

> If $\psi(n)$ is the smallest natural number not found in $C(n)$, asymptotically, how fast does $\psi$ grow?

The first few values of $\psi$ are

$$2,3,5,10,26,178,\dots$$

[Here's a program that outputs $\psi$](https://tio.run/##Vc29DoIwFIbh3atgbIWe0MHFenTgMpozaCIJqR75TWih117Bze39hi9PPz18ShWqKy980TdbFprOYkYR0GNlWWmSMDThaUQJALOE971dVrf@TV59jjZYR3mwTMVex70oRuNh4qaD4dOPMh7qn@VQG@Fy1HLisXllm0S4e6S2q2kzF1NtT5S@) and [here's a program that outputs $C$](https://tio.run/##Vcc7DoMwDADQqzAmBSwiMUFNhxzD8tBKDAjh8pVISM6eirHbe@vxcSlZLDu55GleVBWGG3Wi8ujQkpSGNWyD71tVAcCpYXrPVxjDXyW4HMnTyLkn4eLW4xbH2Do4ZFhg@667jmnOLNWcfg).

---

I'm looking for better bounds and/or asymptotic formulas in the form of

$$\psi(n)\approx x^{y^n}$$

Comment: For testing purposes, you could use [this program](https://tio.run/##Vcc7DoMwDADQqzAmBSwiMUFNhxzD8tBKDAjh8pVISM6eirHbe@vxcSlZLDu55GleVBWGG3Wi8ujQkpSGNWyD71tVAcCpYXrPVxjDXyW4HMnTyLkn4eLW4xbH2Do4ZFhg@667jmnOLNWcfg) to output $C(n)$. However, the numbers get fairly large fairly fast...

Comment: So $\psi(n)\le4^n+1$? Hm...

Comment: It would seem to me that $C(5)$ contains all of the natural numbers from $0$ to $177$, as well as a lot of other numbers. As long as the gap from one consecutive number to the next is less than $178$, we can fill it by adding all of our numbers to the lower number. The smallest gap I can find in $C(5)$ which is larger than $178$ is above $6000$, and $4^6$ is only $4096$.

Comment: yes, I see the pattern of the last element of $C(n)$ as $2^1,2^2,2^4,2^8,...$ so a "brutal" upper bound could be $\psi(n)\le 2^{(2^{n-1})}+1$

Comment: Haha, yes, that is extremely brutal of an upper bound.

Comment: 2 times the smallest prime not in the previous set is one number that will never be present in the current set. Maybe that will give a bound.

Comment: @mathreadler The smallest prime not in $C(4)$ is $29$, but $29\times2=58$, which is in $C(5)$. One way to construct $58$ would be to take $3\times16+20$, and $3,16,20\in C(3)$.

Comment: what, are you allowed to take any combination of multiplication and addition? i thought you had to choose either multiplication **or** addition of two elements in the previous set.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, hence why $C(3+2)$, allowing two steps of operations between the elements of $C(3)$.

Comment: yes if two steps between then you can do that, since all numbers which once get in will remain in the successors.

Comment: But the point is still there. $29$ is the smallest prime $\notin C(4)$, yet $29\times2\in C(5)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt 20 isn't in C(3), rather it's a result of an addition of more than two elements in C(3)

Comment: @Abra But $20=4\times5$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes it is 16+4 too, kind of a tie that makes me go reserve a third color for numbers considered "bigender".

Comment: @simply look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ftju3qm1/21/) just get the gaps and remove additions, they are pretty much familiar prime gaps that are filled with supplementary primes not existing in originated set multiplied by numbers from the same set! my conjecture is that $\phi(n)$ is either a prime not included in $C(n-1)$ or multiplied by a number included in it!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It's worth noting that $C(n)$ is actually *larger* than the set of numbers (individually) obtainable by up to $n$ steps of addition or multiplication starting from 0 or 1.  Let's say $x,y \in C(9)$, then the intermediate values used to construct $x$ may be unavoidably different from those used to construct $y$, so it isn't necessarily true that $xy$ can be built in $10$ steps.

Comment: Just for the reference: my quick-and-dirty program suggests the next two values of $\psi(n)$, following $178$, are $7391$ and $6550891$. For comparison, the cardinality of the $C(n)$ sets would be $2, 3, 5, 12, 53, 679, 67145, 357306081$.

Comment: Cheers: https://oeis.org/A296261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that $\psi(n)=k+1$. It thus follows that

$$\{x:x\in[0,k]\}\subset C(n)$$

By adding these together, we may find that

$$\{k+x:x\in C(n)\}\subset C(n+1)$$

And thus, the simple bound of

$$\psi(n+1)\ge k+k+1=2\psi(n)-1$$

or

> $$\psi(n)\ge2^n+1$$

---

By adding and multiplying, we find that

$$\{k+x,k\cdot x:x\in C(n)\}\subset C(n+1)$$

And by adding these again, we find that

$$\{k\cdot x_0+x_1:x_0,x_1\in C(n)\}\subset C(n+2)$$

Which encompasses all of the numbers from $0$ to $k^2+2k$, hence

$$\psi(n+2)\ge k^2+2k+1=\psi(n)^2$$

or,

> $$\psi(n)\ge2^{2^{n/2}}$$

---

By adding and multiplying instead of just adding in the previous step, we find that

$$\{x_0,x_1k^2:x_0,x_1\in C(n+1)\}\subset C(n+2)$$

And by adding these, once again, we find that

$$\{x_1k^2+x_0:x_0,x_1\in C(n+1)\}\subset C(n+3)$$

which will encompass all of the numbers from $0$ to $2k^3+2k$, hence

$$\psi(n+3)\ge2k^3+2k+1=2\psi(n)^3-6\psi(n)^2+8\psi(n)-3$$

which is not at all pretty, but since $2\psi(n)\ge1$ for all $n$, we get

$$\psi(n+3)\ge2(\psi(n)-1)^3$$

And if $\psi(n)\ge\frac1{1-2^{-1/3}}\approx4.8$, then

$$2(\psi(n)-1)^3\ge\psi(n)^3$$

And thus,

> $$\psi(n)\ge5^{3^{(n-2)/3}},{\rm~large~enough~}n$$

---

Doing this again gives

$$\psi(n+4)\ge2k^5+4k^4+2k^3+k^2+2k$$

And for large enough $k$,

$$2k^5+4k^4+2k^3+k^2+2k>(k+1)^5=\psi(n)^5$$

hence,

> $$\psi(n)\ge5^{5^{(n-2)/4}},{\rm~large~enough~}n$$

---

and in general, I'm expecting

$$\psi(n)\ge2^{(2^x+1)^{(n-y)/(x+2)}}>2^{2^{x(n-y)/(x+2)}}$$

For all $x$, large enough $n$, and some $y$.

Comment: How are you getting $\psi(n_4) \ge 2k^5 + 4k^4 + k^2 + 2k$?

Comment: @Deedlit It's $(k^2+2k)(2k^3+2k)$, that is, we can represent all multiples of $2k^3+2k$ up to that, and the gap may be filled with addition. (IIRC)

Comment: I'm not quite seeing it... to fill in the gaps by addition, we need all the multiples of $2k^3 + 2k$ by C(n+3), and to get those multiples, we need $2k^3 + 2k$ by C(n+2).  How do you get there?

Comment: @Deedlit Note that $$[0,k^2+2k]\cup\{2k^3\}\subset C(n+2)\\\implies\{2k^3x_0:x_0\in[0,k^2+2k]\}\subset C(n+3)\\ [0,2k^3+2k]\subset C(n+3)\\ \implies\{2k^3x_0+x_1:x_0\in [0,k^2+2k],x_1\in [0,2k^3+2k]\}\subset C(n+4)\\ [0,2k^3(k^2+2k)+2k^3+2k]\subset C(n+4)]$$

Answer (score 1):

Building from Simply Beautiful Art's answer, let $A(n)$ be the greatest member of $C(n)$ less than $\psi(n+1)$. Then, $\psi(n+2) \geq \psi(n+1) + A(n)\psi(n)$. If we define $K = \lim \inf_{n->\infty} \frac{A(n)}{\psi(n)}$, then $\psi(n+2) > K\psi(n)\psi(n+1)$, and we should have that $\psi = O(b^{\phi^{n}})$ for some $b$.